# Finding the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(x+1)^{n+2}}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Find the sum of the series and for which values of $x$ does it converge:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(x+1)^{n+2}}{3^n} $$

My attempt:

$$\begin{align}&S_n=(x+1)^2+(x+1)^3/3+...+(x+1)^{n+1}/3^{n} \\ 
-(x+1)^2&S_n=-(x+1)^3/3-...-(x+1)^{n+2}/3^{n}  \\ 
&S_n=\frac{(x+1)^2-(x+1)^{n+2}/3^{n}}{1-(x+1)^2} \end{align}$$

And for $-4<x<2$ we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)^2-(x+1)^{n+2}/3^{n}}{1-(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x+1)^2}{1-(x+1)^2}$$

Which is the sum of the series for $-4<x<2$.

The sum looks a bit odd, is that alright?

**Note:** no integrals or Taylor or Zeta.

Comment: Range of $x$ looks good.  The sum should be as in the answers below though.

Comment: @Mike yeah the $n+2$ must have threw everything off in my attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(x+1)^{n+2}}{3^n}=(x+1)^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac {x+1}{3}\Big)^n=(x+1)^2\frac{1}{1-\frac{x+1}{3}}=\frac{3(x+1)^2}{2-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

The series is of the form
\begin{align}
f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^{n} = \frac{1}{1-t}.
\end{align}
When $t = (x+1)/3$ the value becomes
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{x+1}{3}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{n}}{3^{n}} = \frac{3}{2-x}.
\end{align}
Now multiply by $(x+1)^{2}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{n+2}}{3^{n}} = \frac{3(x+1)^{2}}{2-x}
\end{align}